# taskSnapshot.downloadUrl.toString() dont work in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

[Code Img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BGWaT.jpg)

I'm trying to follow a tutorial but the part that teaches the value of `DownloadURL = taskSnapshot.downloadUrl.toString()` does not work anymore.
I tried to substitute some options like :

```
val DownloadURL = taskSnapshot.storage.downloadUrl.toString()
```

Or :

```
val DownloadURL = ImageRef.downloadUrl.toString()
```

But I only get print values such as :

> com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzu@8a94cv2 and not a valid url.

Comment: Think we need a little bit more code. What is class is `ImageRef` since it seems like you don't follow common casing conventions and is probably a `val`?

Comment: I inserted an image with a code sample and println. I think it has something to do with the firebase-storage version.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this after onSuccessListener.....

`val downloadURL = taskSnapshot.getStorage().getDownloadUrl().toString()`

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that the `getDownloadUrl()` method does not return a URL or a String, it returns a `Task<URI>` based on [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/storage/StorageReference.html#getDownloadUrl()) documentation.

If you would like to get the Uri itself, then you can use the `getResult()` to get the result and then do a `.toString()` on that.

Comment: I also did something like this before creating the topic. If I use:
var url = taskSnapshot.result
I get something like com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask$TaskSnapshot@de56db

Comment: I got it by taking the result, but in a syntax as I posted it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I can not say exactly why it did not work with other syntaxes, but I got the result doing it this way: 
(Firebase implementation version: 16.0.1 / Kotlin)

My solution:

```
mReference.putFile (uri) .addOnFailureListener {
          // failure
       } .addOnSuccessListener () {taskSnapshot ->
          // success
             mReference.downloadUrl.addOnCompleteListener () {taskSnapshot ->

                 var url = taskSnapshot.result
                 println ("url =" + url.toString ())

             }
  }
```